# ultimo theme is not rendering IE stylesheet in IE 8

Tags: magento-1.9, css

There are `styles-ie8.css` & `styles-ie7.css` in ultimo theme under skin folder. I have used developer tool in IE8 and there are all the css files used by the page. You can see in img 1.

img 2 shows the source code which has all the required files. I have tried to move the styles-ie7.css in the base theme. It is also showing in the view source correctly, but IE is not rendering any of the CSS.

What may be the problem?[image]

[image]

Comment: In ultimo demo, everything is fine. But in my website, i think some css classes is changed or modified. Is this responsible for all the problems in IE?

Answer (score 1):

This may not an issue with the theme per-se, but rather a limit of IE8. If I had to guess I would suggest that you are hitting one of the CSS limits that people often aren't aware of in older versions of IE. IE8 will only load 31 style sheets, since the IE specific stylesheets are at the bottom, these often don't load if you have a lot of extensions with their own stylesheets. You might find that enabling css compilation will fix the issue. A slight caveat to this is the fact that it will also only load 4096 selectors per file, so sometimes compilation hits this problem. Good old IE.

Comment: I am already using compressed css and js in my main domain.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you aren't in test though. So are you saying that it doesn't load them in live also?

Comment: test means in my development server.Sorry i can not share the domain name.